# Openstack on Windows

Tags: cloud

Can I run openstack on windows? If yes, where can I get the installer? Is it free ? I can't seem to find the download on openstack Otherwise, do you know of any open source cloud that run on windows?

Comment: hm.... but why on windows?

Comment: Cos im using windows server!

Comment: I dont see the reason why not. Its java after all.

Comment: Pfff I confused with cloudstack :-) It's written in pyton, the compute you should be able to run on windows by copying installed files to windows, but reagrding the storage I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can host Windows VMs, but you can't host in on Windows.

http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/admin/content/creating-a-windows-image.html